# Can git list the tags that occur between two particular commits?

Tags: git, tags, commit

Is there a way to get git to list all the tags that were added in between two commits? That is, only show me the tags that appear between point A and point B.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `git log` command with these options:

```
git log tagA...tagB --decorate --simplify-by-decoration
```

`--decorate` displays the tag names next to the commit, and `--simplify-by-decoration` shows only commits that have been tagged.

Comment: You can also use the commit checksums, which is probably a more appropriate answer to the question: `git log commitA...commitB --decorate --simplify-by-decoration`

Comment: `git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration tagA...tagB`...don't believe everything you read on the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

If you *only* wants the tag name list (in reverse chronological order) between `commit1` and `commit2`, you can combine `git log` with `xargs` and `git tag --points-at`:

```
git log commit1..commit2 --simplify-by-decoration --format=format:%h | xargs -L1 git tag --points-at
```

Answer (score 1):

This command efficiently lists all tags between commits `commit1` and `commit2` (not including `commit1` itself).

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:%D commit1..commit2 | \
    grep -o 'tag: [^,)]\+' | sed 's/^tag: //'
```

The `git log ...` command lists the branches and tags referencing each commit in the specified range.  The subsequent commands parse out just the tags.